# Electron-Typescript app crashes due to module

Tags: typescript, electron

I'm trying to build a client that runs on Electron with Typescript, however, I get the following error:

[image]

The `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types"
    ],
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

And `package.json` is like so:

```json
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application written with Typescript",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc --ext .ts ./src",
    "start": "npm run build && electron --no-sandbox ./dist/main.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/electron": "^1.6.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.42",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "electron": "^18.2.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

I've been getting errors no matter what module type I select in `tsconfig` either due to the usage of `require` in generated JS files (which I use as scripts on the browser) or due to the compilation process of TS files. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **"module": "commonjs"** in tsconfig,json and remove **"type": "module"** from package.json